# How to call methods from a C++ library in Android?

Tags: android, c++

I have a huge C++ library for image processing. I would like to use this DLL library in an Android project. How can I call methods in the C++ DLL library in Android?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try JavaCPP. JavaCPP will help you auto generate appropriate code for JNI, and passes it to the C++ compiler to build a native library.

For more details and examples, please see： https://code.google.com/p/javacpp/

Answer (score 0):

via JNI Java Native Interface.

using this keyword will let you find a tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Answer (score 0):

You need the Java Native Interface (JNI)

Oracle has a great set of tutorials on it (google for them).

Also, since you tagged your question Android, I'm presuming that's the platform you need JNI on.

You'll have to look into the Native Development Kit, more info on that here: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html